# How to reduce a PDF size in mac

Tags: pdf, file-conversion, compression

How can I reduce a PDF size that is very big locally in a Mac

Answer (score -1):

1. Open the PDF file with Preview

### [image]

2. Pick File/Export

### [image]

3. Choose Quartz Filter as: "Reduce File Size"

### [image]